# How to Resolve Validation failed: Banner Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: `convert /api/tmp/

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’ am working on dockerized RoR project and when I run all tests(RSPEC), I get the following error, related to ImageMagick:

Error:

```
Failure/Error: article_id { create(:article, :exercise).id }
       
       ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
         Validation failed: Banner Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: `convert /api/tmp/1652907422-50675578162127-0452-5322/card/test.jpg -auto-orient -resize 500x300^ -gravity Center -background rgba(255,255,255,0.0) -extent 500x300 /tmp/image_processing20220518-356-10emhdm.jpg` failed with error:
         convert-im6.q16: insufficient image data in file `/api/tmp/1652907422-50675578162127-0452-5322/card/test.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/ReadJPEGImage/1117.
```

The error is related to a FactoryBot, when I need to upload a file:

`banner            { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/support/images/test.jpg")) }`

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1

RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
  && apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential yarn; apt-get clean

RUN mkdir /api

WORKDIR /api

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

RUN bundle install

COPY package*.json ./ yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Don't use images to display errors -- paste the relevant error code into your question.  Are you sure the test file is a valid image file?

Comment: The docker container has the following ImageMagick version:  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101

Comment: not the docker image -- the test file -- test.jpg.  Looks like a pretty clear error message.